# Vhdl enable without clock question

Tags: vhdl

I made this code and i'm wondering what i have to do to put an enable without a clock.

Do i have to put each line for one if? Thanks in advance.
Like this?

```
if(enable = '1') then
            if(binInput = "0001") then 
            decOut_n <= "1111001"


library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity Bin7SegDecoder is
    port( enable   : in std_logic;
            binInput : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            decOut_n : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));
end Bin7SegDecoder;

architecture Behavioral of Bin7SegDecoder is
begin
        decOut_n <= "1111001" when (binInput = "0001") else --1
                        "0100100" when (binInput = "0010") else --2
                        "0110000" when (binInput = "0011") else --3
                        "0011001" when (binInput = "0100") else --4
                        "0010010" when (binInput = "0101") else --5
                        "0000010" when (binInput = "0110") else --6
                        "1111000" when (binInput = "0111") else --7
                        "0000000" when (binInput = "1000") else --8
                        "0010000" when (binInput = "1001") else --9
                        "0001000" when (binInput = "1010") else --A
                        "0000011" when (binInput = "1011") else --B
                        "1000110" when (binInput = "1100") else --C
                        "0100001" when (binInput = "1101") else --D
                        "0000110" when (binInput = "1110") else --E
                        "0001110" when (binInput = "1111") else --F
                        "1000000"; --0

    end if;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with an enable and no clock?

Comment: Roman's answer is good, as is Jeff's comment. But you missed the first step ... defining what you want to happen when the enable is false. That can go in an "else" clause in Roman's second solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert condition in each line:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity Bin7SegDecoder is
    port( 
        enable   : in std_logic;
        binInput : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        decOut_n : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)
    );
end Bin7SegDecoder;

architecture Behavioral of Bin7SegDecoder is
begin
    process(binInput, enable)
    begin
        decOut_n <= "1111001" when (binInput = "0001") and enable = '1' else --1
                    "0100100" when (binInput = "0010") and enable = '1' else --2
                    "0110000" when (binInput = "0011") and enable = '1' else --3
                    "0011001" when (binInput = "0100") and enable = '1' else --4
                    "0010010" when (binInput = "0101") and enable = '1' else --5
                    "0000010" when (binInput = "0110") and enable = '1' else --6
                    "1111000" when (binInput = "0111") and enable = '1' else --7
                    "0000000" when (binInput = "1000") and enable = '1' else --8
                    "0010000" when (binInput = "1001") and enable = '1' else --9
                    "0001000" when (binInput = "1010") and enable = '1' else --A
                    "0000011" when (binInput = "1011") and enable = '1' else --B
                    "1000110" when (binInput = "1100") and enable = '1' else --C
                    "0100001" when (binInput = "1101") and enable = '1' else --D
                    "0000110" when (binInput = "1110") and enable = '1' else --E
                    "0001110" when (binInput = "1111") and enable = '1' else --F
                    "1000000"; --0
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

OR make one `if` for all statement:

```
...
architecture Behavioral of Bin7SegDecoder is
begin
    process(binInput, enable)
    begin
        if enable = '1' then
            decOut_n <= "1111001" when (binInput = "0001") else --1
                        "0100100" when (binInput = "0010") else --2
                        "0110000" when (binInput = "0011") else --3
                        "0011001" when (binInput = "0100") else --4
                        "0010010" when (binInput = "0101") else --5
                        "0000010" when (binInput = "0110") else --6
                        "1111000" when (binInput = "0111") else --7
                        "0000000" when (binInput = "1000") else --8
                        "0010000" when (binInput = "1001") else --9
                        "0001000" when (binInput = "1010") else --A
                        "0000011" when (binInput = "1011") else --B
                        "1000110" when (binInput = "1100") else --C
                        "0100001" when (binInput = "1101") else --D
                        "0000110" when (binInput = "1110") else --E
                        "0001110" when (binInput = "1111") else --F
                        "1000000"; --0
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

But anyway you shouldn't put `if` outside of 
`architecture Behavioral of Bin7SegDecoder is
begin
...
end Behavioral` 
this part of code

Comment: This will infer latches. The asker should get into the habit of designing using clocked/synchronous processes.

Comment: Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Bin7SegDecoder.vhd(15) near text "when";  expecting ";"
I already tried the 2 options you gave me but what i really want is the second one. I don't know why but it's giving me an error. I usually do it with a clock but this is an exercise I need to do. Thanks.

PS: when enable is '0', the output is none in spite of the entries!

Comment: If you need a none on output when enable is 0 you can add follow line before `end if`  `else decOut_n <= (others => 'X')` for example, or other value what would you like to receive. Which simulator did you use? I tried to compile this code and it works well without any errors or warnings... Just one notice, for constructions like `out <= a when input = 'value' else b;` your compiler should support VHDL-2008 standard. May be this is the cause why you got the error?